# ElasticSearch 1x - aggregate on object conditions

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I want to aggregate on data, which has inner objects. For example:

```
{
    "_index": "product_index-en",
    "_type": "elasticproductmodel",
    "_id": "000001111",
    "_score": 6.3316255,
    "_source": {
        "productId": "11111111111",
        "productIdOnlyLetterAndDigit": "11111111111",
        "productIdOnlyDigit": "11111111111",
        "productNumber": "11111111111",
        "name": "Glow Plug",
        "nameOnlyLetterAndDigit": "glowplug",
        "productImageLarge": "11111111111.jpg",
        "itemGroupId": "11111",
        "relatedProductIds": [],
        "dataAreaCountries": [
            "fra",
            "pol",
            "uk",
            "sie",
            "sve",
            "atl",
            "ita",
            "hol",
            "dk"
        ],
        "oemItems": [
            {
                "manufactorName": "BERU",
                "manufacType": "0"
            },
            {
                "manufactorName": "LUCAS",
                "manufacType": "0"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to be able aggregates oemItems.manufactorName values, but only where oemItems.manufacType is "0". I have tried a number of examples, such as the accepted one here ( [Elastic Search Aggregate into buckets on conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36819975/elastic-search-aggregate-into-buckets-on-conditions) ), but I just cannot seem to wrap my head around it.

I've  tried following, hopeing it will aggragate on manufacType first, which it does, and then manufactorName for each type, which it seems to display correct hit count. However, buckets for manufactorName are empty:

```
GET /product_index-en/_search
{
"size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "baked_goods": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "oemItems"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "test1": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "oemItems.manufacType",
            "size": 500
          },
          "aggs": {
            "test2": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "oemItems.manufactorName",
                "size": 500
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the result:

```
{
   "took": 27,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 471214,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "baked_goods": {
         "doc_count": 677246,
         "test1": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
               {
                  "key": "0",
                  "doc_count": 436557,
                  "test2": {
                     "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                     "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                     "buckets": []
                  }
               },
               {
                  "key": "1",
                  "doc_count": 240689,
                  "test2": {
                     "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                     "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                     "buckets": []
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I have also tried to add a nested term filter, to only look at oemItems which have manufacType 1 with following query. However, it returns Objects where oemItems include manufacType 1, meaning it oemItems within products still contain either 1 or 0 manufacType. I don't see how doing an aggregate on this response will only return oemItems.manufactorName where oemItems.manufacType is 0

```
GET /product_index-en/_search 
{
        "query" : { "match_all" : {} },
        "filter" : {
            "nested" : {
                "path" : "oemItems",
                "filter" : {
                    "bool" : {
                        "must" : [
                            {
                                "term" : {"oemItems.manufacType" : "1"}
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }    
}
```

Comment: First, you need to make sure that `oemItems` is of `nested` type in your mapping. Is that the case?

Comment: @Val No, it is not of nested type. I will change it and see if that helps.

Comment: @Val I've set it to nested and added an example in my post.

Comment: If you need only the names where `manufacType = 0` you should add a `nested` `term` filter and then you can only have a single terms aggregation for the `manufactorName` field. Try it out.

Comment: @Val any chance you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good start so far. Just try it like this:

```
POST /product_index-en/_search
{
  "size": 0,  
  "query": {
     "nested": {
        "path": "oemItems",
        "query": {
           "term": {
              "oemItems.manufacType": "0"
           }
        }
     }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "baked_goods": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "oemItems"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "test1": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "oemItems.manufactorName",
            "size": 500
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Problem is that Object.oemItems can contain objects which have manufacType 1, 0 or multiple of either. So hits returned by the query will include Objects which also have manufactorType 1, in addition to 0, and when I aggregate on such results, I end up with both manufacType 1 and 0. I imagine I would need to add a filter to the aggregation, so it only returns oemItems with manufacType 0?

Comment: Try it out, it should work, because nested fields are distinct documents underneath.

Comment: Appreciate your help Val. I did, but buckets in test1 are empty

Comment: argh! Appearently there's "exact" suffix I had to use on the manufactorName. Bucket returns items now - awesomeness of working on things other people wrote! Thanks so much Val. I will now do a bunch of testing to ensure there results are correct, and if so I'll accept your answer. Have a nice day!

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out!